# Where is smoking allowed in South Korea?

Tags: south-korea, smoking

I heard on a few YouTube travel videos that there are "stricter than normal" restrictions on where smoking is allowed in South Korea, especially in Seoul.

Are there any signs that I should watch out for to determine where smoking is allowed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smoking 10 meters within bus station [in Gyeonggi-do], (10 meters within) subway station exit[in Seoul and Gyeonggi-do], any places with [this sign](http://www.artsign.co.kr/shop/item.php?it_id=0466), most public restrooms, 강남대로 [Gangnam Daero] in Seoul, all government-related buildings, restaurants, bus/train, medical facility,  will result in KRW 100000 (about US$100) fine.

Basically, look for the sign, and avoid smoking in public if you are near subway station exit/bus station and in Gangnam.